# Missing compiler error in QtCreator and Qt5.1.0 on Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: lubuntu, qt, compiler

I can't compile any program in QtCreator on Lubuntu 13.04. I have this error:

```
QtCreator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options
```

First of all, I installed from Synaptic gcc-mingw32 and  mingw32 with dependencies, so the list of downloading packages files looked like this:

```
binutils (version 2.23.2-2ubuntu1) will be installed
binutils-mingw-w64-i686 (version 2.22.90.20120919-0ubuntu1+2) will be installed
binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64 (version 2.22.90.20120919-0ubuntu1+2) will be installed
cpp-4.6 (version 4.6.4-1ubuntu1) will be installed
g++-4.6 (version 4.6.4-1ubuntu1) will be installed
g++-mingw-w64-i686 (version 4.6.3-13ubuntu1+8) will be installed
g++-mingw-w64-x86-64 (version 4.6.3-13ubuntu1+8) will be installed
gcc-4.6 (version 4.6.4-1ubuntu1) will be installed
gcc-4.6-base (version 4.6.4-1ubuntu1) will be installed
gcc-mingw-w64-base (version 4.6.3-13ubuntu1+8) will be installed
gcc-mingw-w64-i686 (version 4.6.3-13ubuntu1+8) will be installed
gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 (version 4.6.3-13ubuntu1+8) will be installed
gfortran-mingw-w64-i686 (version 4.6.3-13ubuntu1+8) will be installed
gfortran-mingw-w64-x86-64 (version 4.6.3-13ubuntu1+8) will be installed
libc-dev-bin (version 2.17-0ubuntu5) will be installed
libc6-dev (version 2.17-0ubuntu5) will be installed
libstdc++6-4.6-dev (version 4.6.4-1ubuntu1) will be installed
linux-libc-dev (version 3.8.0-27.40) will be installed
manpages-dev (version 3.44-0ubuntu1) will be installed
mingw-w64-i686-dev (version 2.0.3-1) will be installed
mingw-w64-x86-64-dev (version 2.0.3-1) will be installed
mingw32 (version 4.2.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1) will be installed
mingw32-binutils (version 2.20-0.2) will be installed
mingw32-runtime (version 3.15.2-0ubuntu1) will be installed
```

Then I downloaded newest Qt 5.1.0 for Linux 32-bit from qt-project.org/downloads and I installed it without any problems. In installation options I had checked "gcc".

Then, I created new project. In Kit Selection I had default checked "Desktop Qt 5.1.0 GCC 32bit". I wrote some code, tried to compile it, and I have mentioned error about compiler. I thought QtCreator will detect gcc (or mingw).

In Options window, section "Build & Run", tab Compilers I have nothing. So I added new compiler GCC and set following file:

```
/home/rafal/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc/bin/qmake
```

But I have no idea if is this the right file.
I set ABI to: x86, linux, generic, elf, 32 bit, but also I'm not sure about it.
Then, in "Kits" tab I added new one, and this one has GCC compiler. I set this kit to default.
I go back to the code, I try to compile it once again, and then I have this error:

```
18:03:16: Running steps for project TestApp...
18:03:16: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
18:03:16: Could not start process "make" 
Error while building/deploying project TestApp (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 GCC 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
18:03:16: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

I also installed g++, and I get the same.

And I don't know what to do.

Can someone help me, please? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Problem solved. I had to install compilers using `$ sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Answer (score 1):

The OP solved the problem by installing `build-essential`.
To install it just type the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```